# Objective-C: Check if using enum option

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a custom object that is using a typedef enum.  If I set a few of the enum options for my object, how can I check to see if those are being used?

```
typedef enum {
    Option1,
    Option2,
    Option3
} Options;
```

When creating my object I might use:

```
myobject.options = Option1 | Option2;
```

How can I then later check which enum options were set? Such as:

```
if (myobject.options == Option1) {
  // Do something
}

if (myobject.options == Option2) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to do bitwise logic for your options parameter, then you should define your enum so that each option only has a single bit set:

```
typedef enum {
    Option1 = 1,       // 00000001
    Option2 = 1 << 1,  // 00000010
    Option3 = 1 << 2   // 00000100
} Options;
```

Then you set your options using the bitwise OR operator:

```
myObject.options = Option1 | Option2;
```

and check which options have been set using the bitwise AND operator:

```
if(myObject.options & Option1) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get an error: "Invalid operands to binary &.  Ideas on this error?

Comment: @glorifiedHacker - Do you know why this wouldn't be working for me?

Comment: "Invalid operands to binary &" means that one of the arguments of the & operator is not a valid input. Both arguments have to be of equal length. To ensure this is the case, return type of `myObject.options` should be either `Options` or `int`.

Comment: @glorifiedhacker: great answer!  I was wondering, though, how would I check to see if myObject.options has 2 out of 3 of those values in one if statement?
For example, in pseudo-code:
if (myObject.options == (either Option1 or Option2))

Comment: @glorifiedHacker: I think I figured it out just by thinking about it haha.

Would it be the following?

if (myObject.options & (Option1 | Option2))

Comment: what would be the maximum number of options? from your code seems that we can have up to 8 options, is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use an enum for this, or at least not use the standard numbering.

```
#define Option1 1
#define Option2 2
#define Option3 4
#define Option4 8
#define Option5 16
```

The values need to be powers of two, so you can combine them. A value of 3 means options 1 + 2 are chosen. You wouldn't be able to make that distinction if 3 was a valid value for one of the other options.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to define the enum using `NS_OPTIONS`. This is the Apple recommended way to create such enums.

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, Options) {
    Options1 = 1 << 0,
    Options2 = 1 << 1,
    Options3 = 1 << 2,
};
```

Then, as it has already been said, you can assign values by doing:

```
myObject.options = Option1 | Option2;
```

and check them:

```
if (myObject.options & Option1) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((myobject.options & Option1) == Option1)
```

Comment: in objc you don't need the ==, I spend most of my time in macruby, where you do.

Comment: and yes, Hollance is correct. I missed the fact that you hadn't made your enum actually be powers of 2, so they can't function as a bitmask.