# Objective C : validity check for an enum variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I am having a delegate function which asks for `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle` from delegate.

```
@protocol StatusViewCustomizationDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle)activityIndicatorStyle;

@end
```

Inside a private function I check if delegate responds to this selector and if it responds I call the method. Below is the code:

```
-(void)configureView
{
   UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle activityIndicatorStyleFromDelegate;
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(activityIndicatorViewStyle)])
    {
        activityIndicatorStyleFromDelegate = [self.delegate activityIndicatorStyle];
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to check the enum value I received in `activityIndicatorStyleFromDelegate` variable is a valid `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle` enum value?

Edit:
`UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle` is an iOS defined enum.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle) {
    UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge,
    UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite,
    UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray,
};
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154304/objective-c-check-if-using-enum-option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, when checking enum values you're limited to one of two methods.

If the enum values are in a contiguous sequence, you can check the value is within its range:

```
if (activityIndicatorStyle >= UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge && 
    activityIndicatorStyle <= UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray) {
    NSLog(@"Good");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Bad");
}
```

Otherwise you'll just have to test check against each value in turn:

```
switch (activityIndicatorStyle) {
    case UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray:
    case UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite:
    case UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge:
        NSLog(@"Good");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Bad");
}
```

Comment: Second one looks more descriptive and clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
if (style >= UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge &&
    style <= UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

Comment: `UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle` is not user defined.

Comment: You mean Apple :p, but yeah they use NSUIntegers for more recent enums.

Comment: @Schemetrical Yeah.  You think they are infallible?

Comment: Of course, this relies on the enum values being contiguous.

Comment: @AshleyMills Which they are.

Comment: Which they are! (Didn't read the question properly - was thinking generally).   Of course, this could change…

Comment: @trojanfoe I never said they were infallible, and I'm assuming its that they are reluctant to change old APIs to prevent problems (god knows what people are doing to compare enums).

Answer (score 0):

You can take the last value of the enum and compare if the supplied enum is less or equal than the last value of the enum, so:

```
- (void)configureView
{
   UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle activityIndicatorStyleFromDelegate;
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(activityIndicatorViewStyle)])
    {
        if ([self.delegate activityIndicatorStyle] >= UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge &&
    [self.delegate activityIndicatorStyle] <= UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray) {
            activityIndicatorStyleFromDelegate = [self.delegate activityIndicatorStyle];
        }
    }
}
```

Also, a common convention is to [add one more enumeration that is called `num_types`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162047/3197253) and you can check if the enums are less than `num_types`, but this is not possible in your context.